# Can apache flink be used to save to database and then publish to kafka in a fault tolerant manner?

Tags: apache-flink

Can apache flink be used to save to database and then publish to kafka in a fault tolerant manner? If it fails publish to kafka, then it should not save to database or resume to publish. Can we use flink for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest idea to solve this issue would be to split the pipeline into two separate jobs/services. The first one could be a simple Flink job that does what it needs to do and then writes the output to Kafka. The other one could be some external service/Kafka connect/lambda or Flink job too. It would stream the data from Kafka to Database.

This way You would be sure that if the first job fails to produce anything then nothing will be produced to the database.